# store data from txt files in table mysql

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to make a program where I would read data from txt files and store them in tables. The user would give the directory of the files and then would create the table with specific fields.

Then I have to fill the each table with the data that it has. Does anyone could help me how I would do this? The .txt files have data as these that are shown in the image:[image]
The two columns are seperated by tab. 
I had tried the code below but I get error:

```
java.sql.SQLException:at part1.importData(part1.java:31)
    at part1.main(part1.java:16)
```

The code that I have tried is:

```
public class notepad {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3300/mydb", "root", "root");

        String dirpath = "";
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please give the directory:");
            dirpath = scanner1.nextLine();
            File fl = new File(dirpath);
            if (fl.canRead())

                break;
            System.out.println("Error:Directory does not exists");
        }

        try {
            String files;
            File folder = new File(dirpath);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT")) {
                        List<File> txtFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
                        txtFiles.add(listOfFiles[i]);
                        String[] parts = files.split("\\.");
                        String tablename = parts[0];
                        for (File txtFile : txtFiles) {
                            List sheetData = new ArrayList();

                            try {
                                FileReader in = new FileReader(txtFile);
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                                String line = br.readLine();
                                while (line != null) {
                                    System.out.println(line);
                                    line = br.readLine();
                                }
                                in.close();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                            showExcelData(sheetData);
                            getCreateTable1(con, tablename);
                            importData(con, txtFile);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static String getCreateTable1(Connection con, String tablename) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String createtable = "CREATE TABLE "
                    + tablename
                    + " ( text VARCHAR(255), price int )";
            System.out.println("Create a new table in the database");
            stmt.executeUpdate(createtable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static void importData(Connection con, File txtFile) {

        Statement stmt;
        String query;
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + txtFile
                    + "' INTO TABLE tablename (text,price);";

            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stmt = null;
        }

    }
```

Could anyone help me how I would do it? My difficulty is when I am tring to import the data.

Comment: Please edit your post. You have error in SQL query, that is specific to SQL. It has nothing to do with Java or JDBC. Remote java code, leave only query and retag to MySQL. First try to invoke command from mysql console to get more precise SQL error code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you trying to pass File to the query, while AFAIK it should be the full path of the file, like:

> 'C:\temp\data1.txt'

So in this function you should use:

```
 private static void importData(Connection con, File txtFile) {

        query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + txtFile.getAbsolutePath()
                + "' INTO TABLE tablename (text,price);";
```

, please note this will only work if you're on localhost, for remote server, it would be better to do this in batch insert which means you need to rewrite the whole code.

Comment: I updated my answer, so .getAbsolutePath() could be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look in command Load Data Infile. That query is not correct. See this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html